# Unintelligible Segmentation Fault with C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
void Update_Structure_Factor ()
{
    double Ssin [121][121][121];
    double Scos [121][121][121];
    double kdotr;
    int ik;
    double Sk_  [66];
    int howmany [66];

    for ( int i=0; i<x_.size(); ++i )
    {
        for ( int k1=0; k1<=120; ++k1 )
        {
            for ( int k2=0; k2<=120; ++k2 )
            {
                for ( int k3=0; k3<=120; ++k3 )
                {
                    kdotr = (double)dQ*( (k1-60)*x_[i][0] + (k2-60)*x_[i][1] + (k3-60)*x_[i][1] );
                    Ssin[k1][k2][k3] += (double)sin(kdotr);
                    Scos[k1][k2][k3] += (double)cos(kdotr);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for ( int k1=0; k1<=120; ++k1 )
    {
        for ( int k2=0; k2<=120; ++k2 )
        {
            for ( int k3=0; k3<=120; ++k3 )
            {
                double k = (double)dQ*sqrt( pow((k1-60),2) + pow((k2-60),2) + pow((k3-60),2) );
                ik = round(k/0.1);
                Sk_[ik] += Ssin[k1][k2][k3]*Ssin[k1][k2][k3] + Scos[k1][k2][k3]*Scos[k1][k2][k3];
                ++howmany[ik];
            }
        }
    }

    for ( int i=0; i<66; ++i )
        Sk[i] += (double)Sk_[i]/howmany[i];
}
```

Line 34 causes the problem, i.e. `Sk_[ik] += Ssin[k1][k2][k3]*Ssin[k1][k2][k3] + Scos[k1][k2][k3]*Scos[k1][k2][k3];` The "funny" thing is that if I replace `Ssin[k1][k2][k3]*Ssin[k1][k2][k3] + Scos[k1][k2][k3]*Scos[k1][k2][k3]` with, say, 2, it works.

Please, help!

P.S.: `x_` and `Sk` are members of the class this method `Update_Structure_Factor` belongs to.

Comment: Could you post the declaration of `x_`. BTW `Ssin`, `Scos` and `Sk_` are all uninitialised.

Comment: No, they are, at the beginning of the class.

Comment: ‘vector<array<double,3>> x_;’

Comment: `ik = round(k/0.1); Sk_[ik] += Ssin[k1][k2][k3]*Ssin[k1][k2][k3] + Scos[k1][k2][k3]*Scos[k1][k2][k3];` looks suspicious. What guarantee that `ik < 66`?

Comment: Is `(k3-60)*x_[i][1]` a typo? Looks like maybe it should be `(k3-60)*x_[i][2]`

Comment: The math. =) Besides, I am very sure it can access Sk_.

Comment: Well I would add a check, or write `Sk_.at(ik)`, bugs are often caused by assumptions which turn out to be incorrect.

Comment: The fact is that if I replace `Ssin[k1][k2][k3]*Ssin[k1][k2][k3] + Scos[k1][k2][k3]*Scos[k1][k2][k3]` with, e.g., 2, there is no segmentation fault.

Comment: It's possible that, if you do have an out of bounds access on `Sk_`, you will be corrupting other variables like `k1`, `k2` and `k3`. So it's entirely possible that replacing that expression with `2` would stop the seg fault happening.

Comment: No, @john, I'm very sure there are no problems with the indices of `Sk_` or possible out of bounds accesses.

Comment: Bugs (especially unintelligible ones) are often caused by incorrect assumptions. Have you actually checked with `if (ik < 0 || ik >= 66) ...`? If not that is the first thing I would do.

Comment: Yes. I tried this, and also to initialize `Sk_` with much more elements than needed.

Comment: Have you considered running it in the debugger and examining the variables when it crashes?

Comment: @RetiredNinja: No. How can I do that?

Comment: Actually, by making arrays `Ssin` and `Scos` static now it works, but it takes very much more time.

Comment: Ok, now I'd like to know why to downvote my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting an awful lot of data on the stack here - about 14MB each for Ssin and Scos.  Not knowing which C++ compiler you're using or the target hardware, I'd nevertheless think that something related to stack abuse is a reasonable guess.  You're almost certainly better off making these arrays static (thread-unsafe) or allocated off the heap.

Unrelated, but C++ does not automatically initialize stack variables for you.  Your code assumes the arrays start out with zeros.  Making the arrays static will in fact perform the 0 init the first time, but you'd have to clear them again on each call.

Comment: I'm using `gcc/4.7.0` on a high-performance cluster. I also tried to initialize the arrays with zeros before, but it doesn't help. I'll try to make them static.

Comment: I made them static. It seems to work, but it's taking a huge amount of time.

Comment: Ok, it worked, but it's much (very much) more time-consuming. Something which I guess should be expected, since the accesses to these arrays shouldn't be parallelized anymore (isn't it?).

Comment: The time is being spent performing the initialization to 0 that you skipped before.  If you're initializing the arrays with a loop, std::fill or memset to 0 might be significantly faster.

Comment: I don't think so. Even before asking I tried with initializing everything to 0 (even if I didn't make the arrays static), and it wasn't so time-consuming. Besides, it didn't work.

Comment: Anyway, I simply used `={0}` in order to initialize everything to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found an alternative way to make the code work without using the `static` keyword. I simply sampled half of `k1`, `k2` and `k3`, even if they still cover the whole domain I am interested in (i.e., `ik` from 0 to 65). In this way, I don't obtain the segmentation fault error but the program works in a reasonable time.